# How can I use one by one sql data in php?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, foreach

I'm using PDO::FETCH_ASSOC and i'm trying to get data in mysql. This is my sql data:

```
Array
(
    [lessons_media_id] => 1
    [lessons_id] => 1
    [lessons_media_photo] => http://link1
)
Array
(
    [lessons_media_id] => 2
    [lessons_id] => 1
    [lessons_media_photo] => http://link2
)
```

I use foreach:

```
<?php
foreach($data as $key => $value){
echo $value["lessons_media_photo"];
}
?>
```

Outputs:
http://link1 http://link2

I wanna use one by one. How can I do this ?
Examples:

```
<p>http://link1</p>
<img src="http://link2">
```

Comment: just echo it along with the markup `echo "<html tags>your value here</html tags>"`

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
<?php
foreach($data as $key => $value){
echo '<p>'.$value["lessons_media_photo"].'</p>';
echo '<img src = '.$value["lessons_media_photo"].'>';
}
?>
```